# UI Bootstrap not working in ASP-MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use UI Bootstrap in a VS2013 MVC project with standard "out of the box" bootstrap support.

I've added: 'Install-Package Angular.UI.Bootstrap' in PM

added a script tag in my layout file:

and created a depencency:

```
var collegeApp = angular.module('collegeApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

simplecode like this won't run:

```
   <accordion close-others="true">
        <accordion-group heading="Static Header, initially expanded" is-open="true">
            This content is straight in the template.
        </accordion-group>
    </accordion>
```

It says "accordion" is an Unknown Element and doesn't render anything... Is there anybody that ran into these "startup" problems like i do and can give me a hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after updating the references to angular and bootstrap it works!

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```